# SQL Server - How to record which entries are duplicates?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design, sql-update

I am working on a project in SQL Server to create an audit database from 3 different criteria. The 3 separate queries each work exactly how I want them to and are used to populate respective temp tables. From that I used a union to bring those 3 into one final aggregated temp table. The problem I am having is that some of my entries meet the criteria of more than one of my initial queries, creating duplicates. I want to remove these duplicates, but also be able to record that the entries came up on multiple bases.

```
SELECT * INTO #all_audits FROM
(SELECT * FROM #audita 
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM #auditb
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM #auditc) as tmp
```

I started by adding a column in each initial temp table with the name of the audit. This worked without a hitch to be able to tell on the union. Now I was thinking that I should add another column for audit type 2, to record the second audit that an entry was flagged on, but I'm not quite sure how to go about it. I know an update set sequence would probably work for my current format that I was thinking of.

```
ALTER TABLE #all_audits  ADD AuditType2 varchar(255)
```

Each of these tables above shares the same primary key. Tables also each have a column "AuditType" that labels which audit they are from.

Now this is probably simple, but the code to actually perform that match and still remove duplicates is where I am stuck. Something like this?

```
UPDATE #all_audits 
SET AuditType2 = AuditType
FROM #all_audits
WHERE Primary_Key IN
        (SELECT Primary_Key
        FROM #all_audits
        GROUP BY Primary Key HAVING COUNT(*)>1)
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 1):

If I am correctly understanding your requirement, you want set new column `auditType2` on rows whose `primary_key` is not unique.

If so, you could use window functions and an updateable cte:

```
with cte as (
    select auditType, auditType2, count(*) over(partition by primary_key) cnt
    from  #all_audit
)
update cte set auditType2 = auditType where cnt > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest creating the table as:

```
SELECT a.*,
       STRING_AGG(this_audit, ',') OVER (PARTITION BY primarykey) as all_audits
INTO #all_audits
FROM (SELECT a.*, 'a' as this_audit FROM #audita a
      UNION ALL
      SELECT a.*, 'b' as this_audit FROM #auditb a
      UNION ALL
      SELECT a.*, 'c' as this_audit FROM #auditc a
     ) a;
```

This concatenates all the audits together, so it does not assume that a "primary key" is only in one audit.